# The type or namespace name SecurityRulesAttribute does not exist in the namespace System.Security

Tags: .net, xslt, msxml

We are upgrading our app from .NET 3.5 to 4.5.2. During the tests, when loading an XSLT, getting below error:

> Exception thrown: 'System.Xml.Xsl.XslLoadException' in System.Xml.dll
>
> Additional information: The type or namespace name
>   'SecurityRulesAttribute' does not exist in the namespace
>   'System.Security' (are you missing an assembly reference?)

```
    Dim settings = New XsltSettings(True, True)
    Dim xslt = New XslCompiledTransform()
    Dim urlResolver = New XmlUrlResolver()

    xslt.Load(path, settings, urlResolver) 'getting error here
```

We are using script blocks using [msxml scripts](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/data/xml/script-blocks-using-msxsl-script). Googling suggested that we need to  set EnableScript to true on XsltSettings, which is done in our case (via constructor).

I created a standalone console application using the same code, and same xslt path, it is working fine (in .NET 4.5.2 itself). Has anyone faced this issue before ?

**EDIT:**

There is option to use [XSLT Extension Objects](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/data/xml/xslt-extension-objects). But with so many `msxml` scripts already present, still trying to use them as first option.